# Marquee Slider lacks after few iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, marquee

I have created a marquee slider. After a few iterations the marquee lacks.

I want to have the marquee to have full view-width. As I can see the marquee is lacking less on smaller devices. I have created other similar marquees before with different elements and never had that problem. The empty list elements I have implemented to have a spacing between the text elements, but the icons should be next to the text as they are currently.

```js
  (function marquee() {
    var marqueeWrapper = $('.js-marquee');
        var FPS = (60/100); // 60fps
        var SLIDESPEED = 1000; // default | lower is faster

    marqueeWrapper.each(function (index, element) {
      var _marqueeWrapper = $(element);
      var _marqueeTracks = $('>ul', _marqueeWrapper);
      var _marqueeSlides = $('>ul>li', _marqueeWrapper);
            var _marqueeWidth = parseFloat(_marqueeSlides.last().position().left + _marqueeSlides.last().outerWidth(true));
      var shifted = _marqueeWrapper.attr('data-marquee-shift') || false;

      var SPEED = (_marqueeWrapper.attr('data-marquee-speed') * _marqueeSlides.length) || (SLIDESPEED * _marqueeSlides.length); 
      var frames = SPEED * FPS;
      var steps = _marqueeWidth / frames; // distance elems will move each frames
      var posX = 0;
      var tempSteps;

      function _clone() {
        var times = Math.ceil(_marqueeWrapper.outerWidth(true) / _marqueeWidth) + 1;
        _marqueeTracks.each(function () {
          $('>ul', _marqueeWrapper).empty();
          var sliders = _marqueeSlides;
          for (i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
            sliders.clone().appendTo(($(this)));
          }
        })
      }

      function _animated() {
        posX += -steps;
        _marqueeTracks.css({
          transform: 'translate3d(' + posX + 'px, 0, 0)'
        });
        if (Math.abs(posX) >= _marqueeWidth) {
          posX = 0;
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(_animated);
      }

      function _pause() {
        tempSteps = steps;
        return steps = 0;
      }

      function _resume() {
        return steps = tempSteps;
      }

      function _shiftPosition() {
        if(shifted) return posX = -(_marqueeSlides.first().outerWidth(true)) / 2 ;
      }
      
      /*
      function _registerEvents() {
        _marqueeTracks.on('mouseenter', _pause);
        _marqueeTracks.on('mouseleave', _resume);
        $(window).on('resize', debounce(_clone, 300))
      }*/

      function init() {
        _shiftPosition()
        _clone();
        _animated();
        /*_registerEvents();*/
      }
            
            function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
                var timeout;
                return function () {
                    var context = this,
                        args = arguments;
                    var later = function () {
                        timeout = null;
                        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
                    };
                    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
                };
};// debounce

      init();
    })
  })();
```

```css
.marquee {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee__track {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.marquee__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
.marquee__item {
 height: 80px; 
}
.marquee__item_vegan {
 flex: 0 0 120px; 
 font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Gothic821;
}
.marquee__item_gluten {
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Gothic821;
}
.marquee__item_natural {
  flex: 0 0 130px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Gothic821;
}
.marquee__item_empty {
  flex: 0 0 180px;
}
.marquee__item_small {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
}
.marquee__item_icon {
  width: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-marquee-speed="100" data-marquee-shift="false" class="marquee js-marquee">
    <ul class="marquee__track">
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_small"><img class="marquee__item_icon" src="{{ 'Haken_weiss.svg' | asset_url }}"/></li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_vegan">VEGAN</li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_empty"></li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_small"><img class="marquee__item_icon" src="{{ 'Haken_weiss.svg' | asset_url }}"/></li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_gluten">GLUTENFREI</li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_empty"></li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_small"><img class="marquee__item_icon" src="{{ 'Haken_weiss.svg' | asset_url }}"/></li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_natural">NATURAL</li>
        <li class="marquee__item marquee__item_empty"></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you've reinvented the wheel here. This can be done much more simply with [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Is it 'lags' rather than 'lacks'? Could you say what lags, is it the little jerkiness seen sometimes or does it get worse than that?

Comment: Yeah the little jerkiness sometimes and as well on bigger screens in my case a 27 inch desktop the marque stops after a few iterations and starts again so the elements shift.

Answer (score 0):

The given code seems rather complex for a simple marquee.

While you will need to invoke a little JS at the start (on a load or a resize) to make sure the timing is right for the speed required (it varies depending on viewport width) there seems little to be gained from using JS for the actual animation.

And there may be some loss in using JS which does not guarantee real-time timing (your system may be busy doing other things) and that can introduce lag. Using a CSS method can help to smooth things as there is less need to move back and forth between CPU and GPU.

The given code also performs the animation in steps, moving position, which can be jerkier than translating.

This snippet is stripped down to demonstrate the basic ideas in using HTML and CSS without JS.

As in the code in the question, a second copy of the items is made. This allows the marquee to appear continuous, as the first item disappears to the left it can be seen coming in from the right.

The units used are related to the viewport width so the whole thing is responsive. A CSS animation is used to get the movement, moving the whole 50% of its width, then when the copy comes in it is overwritten by the first part so the movement looks continuous (this is the same technique as used in the given code but with pure CSS rather than JS/CSS).

```css
.marquee,
.marquee * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

.marquee {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee>ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  animation: move 5s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.marquee>ul li {
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: white;
  margin: 5vw;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee__item_vegan,
.marquee__item_gluten,
.marquee__item_natural {
  --bg: linear-gradient(white, white);
  /* just for demo */
}

.marquee>ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  left: -4vw;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80% 80%;
  background-position: bottom left;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <ul>
    <li class="marquee__item_vegan">VEGAN</li>
    <li class="marquee__item_gluten">GLUTENFREI</li>
    <li class="marquee__item_natural">NATURAL</li>
    <li class="marquee__item_vegan">VEGAN</li>
    <li class="marquee__item_gluten">GLUTENFREI</li>
    <li class="marquee__item_natural">NATURAL</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Notes: you may want to reinstate some JS to calculate the timing - depends on  your use case.

The spurious list items have been removed. The imgs which are really just visual clues are added as before pseudo elements. The empty items are not needed. (It's best to keep formatting and content separate, especially for those using assistive technology such as screen readers).